# How to solve Libvlc stream render issue with multiple instance on android Marshmallow?

Tags: android, libvlc

I had to find out [Android VLC player with multiple instance](https://github.com/dariobanfi/multiplevlc)

It works fine with android lollipop(tested).but its not properly works with android-M.also attached the image for reference.[image: Multiple Vlc instance on android marshmellow]

What is the issue with libvlc?Does libvlc multiple instance not support on android-M?

Comment: Exactly why you need libvlc to run in multiple instances ?

Comment: @RonTLV:-Its a requirement that multiple ip camera stream over many surfaces and that surfaces are in gridview(2*2) so got output of n ip camera views with n diffrent surfaces.